# How to expose C++ code in Cocoa-touch library

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use custom C++ code in Swift project.

I have two projects in workspace: a static library with C++ code:

```cpp
//  display_recognition.h

int getNumeralSegment_CPP(unsigned char *image, const int width, const int height, unsigned char *output, const int displayWidth, const int displayHeight, const int rotateHeight, float *separators);
```

Obj-C wrapper of C++ code:

```
#import "iOS_display_recognition.h"
#include "../display_recognition//display_recognition.h"

@implementation iOS_display_recognition

+ (int)getImageNumeralSegment:(unsigned char *)image :(const int)width :(const int)height :(unsigned char *)output :(const int)displayWidth :(const int)displayHeight :(const int)rotateHeight :(float *)separators {
    return getNumeralSegment_CPP(image, width, height, output, displayWidth, displayHeight, rotateHeight, separators);
}

@end
```

and the app project with Swift code:

```swift
let err = iOS_display_recognition.getImageNumeralSegment(time, Int32(cgimg.width), Int32(cgimg.height), numbers, 960, 415, 270, ptrSeparators)
```

I have linked them in XCode, added header references in build settings and included bridging header.

It passes compiler checks but when I try to build the project the following error appears:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>
> "_getNumeralSegment_CPP", referenced from:
>
> +[iOS_display_recognition getImageNumeralSegment::::::::] in 
>   libiOS_display_recognition.a(iOS_display_recognition.o)
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

There is some C++ to obj-C magic but I can't find clear references on how to do it.

Comment: To help troubleshoot the problem, I would suggest putting the C++ code, its Objective-C wrapper (actually, it should be Objective-C++; is it?), and the Swift app code in one project, so that they are all built together. It is possible that the static library was not built for the architecture you are trying to build the application for.